# Bootcamp 'Could not update computer's boot configuration'

Tags: mac, bootcamp, partition, startup, install

I own a MacBookPro 16inch 2019 Touchbar i9. I need to install Windows 10 on it as a second OS, but I cannot get it to work. Each time I use Bootcamp it gives me the following error right at the finishing stage of the instalation: 'Could not update computer's boot configuration'.
So far I have tried:

- 6 different Windows ISOs (official newer/older)
- Installing without Bootcamp
- disabling csrutil and disabling that CMD+R security thing
- Completely resetting my MacBook to Factory Settings
- Resetting NVRAM and SMC (once and twice an install)
- First Aiding my Macintosh HD (once and twice an install)
- Using bcdedit and/or diskpart via Shift+F10 while in installer after the error message pops up [commands did not work btw]
- Mounting disk0 and deleting the EFI folder
- The MBR thing is set to 'protectve', not 'hybrid'

And every single time I get the same error, except like two times when I installed it off a USB and at the start it said it lacked some boot-critical drivers. At this point I am desperate. I **need** to install Windows on it before Dec31, but nothing on the Internet seems to work. Any other suggestions, guys?

Comment: When you tried using USB, did you put the Windows Support Software from Apple on the USB? Was the USB ExFat formatted?

Comment: Yes, I’ve tried downloading the drivers via both Bootcamp Assistant and Brigadier GitHub app, but non of them worked. I had to put the “Windows Support” folder to the root of the USB, did I understand that correctly? Because any time I tried to install windows (even via Bootcamp Assistant) I couldn’t use MacBook’s Trackpad or Keyboard, thus I used an external one. And yes, USB was ExFat formatted via Rufus on Win10 PC.

Comment: The `Windows Support` folder definitely does **NOT** go in the root. Doing so **should** result in failure. I would not recommend using Rufus unless you need an older release of windows 10. You should be able to create a Windows 10 installer USB flash drive by just using macOS. You do not need to use PC.

Comment: Can you post your Mac's Model Identifier? This can be found using the System Information application. Can you post the contents of the `Windows Support` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This is not a complete answer, but rather is a start of an answer. I assume more may need to be added later.

[Apple explicitly states](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201468) you should download Windows 10 from [this website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO). I know it is possible to use Rufus or Microsoft's media creation tool. However,  doing so may lead to downloading different files from what Apple instructed you to download. So there may exist the possibility that a failure to install could result from not following Apple's instructions.

Furthermore, you should Safari on your MacBook Pro 16-inch 2019 Touch Bar Core i9 to download the current Windows 10 ISO file. If you have selected in Safari preferences to "Show develop menu in the menu bar", then make the User Agent is set to the Default.

The proper placement of the Window Support Software on the USB flash drive has not changed since Windows 7. You can read Apple's instructions which are recorded in step 11 of [Follow these steps if you downloaded version 5 of Windows Support Software](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT205016#version5). The Windows Support Software for you Mac probably no longer includes an `AutoUnattend.xml` file.

> Note: There are versions (probably the latest) of the Boot Camp Assistant where the `AutoUnattend.xml` file is generated and placed by the Boot Camp Assistant in the root folder of the volume containing the Windows 10 installation files before booting from this volume. If necessary, you can extract the file from this location.

Comment: Hm... Seems quite odd. I've seen this website many times in videos and on websites, yet when I clicked the link they provided - I've always got onto the Media Creation Tool page, not the ISO download page. I'll try doing it with the ISO and come back as soon as I finish, hope this time it goes well. And yeah, by 'putting the Windows Support folder in the root directory of the USB' I meant extracting its contents into the root folder. 
Thanks a lot for your reply, David!

Comment: The website detects the browser and operating system, then adjusts what is shown to the viewer. For example, if you change Safari's User Agent to Microsoft Edge, then you will see the Media Creation Tool page.

Comment: Yep, it worked! Sorry for taking so long, had some family stuff to do and the Internet connection was not stable too. The strange thing is that my colleague asked me to help him setup Bootcamp on his MacBook a year ago with a specific ISO that he said ‘was created via Media Creation Tool’. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Glad you were able to install Windows 10. FYI, you probably would be able to install Windows 11 on your Mac.

Comment: Enough shenanigans for now, but thanks a bunch!